# Wildfly 8.0.1 jboss-as:deploy just hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am new to Wildfly and am struggling to use the Maven command `mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy` to deploy one of the quick starts from jboss tutorial.

I can deploy the quick start from JBoss Developer Studio but when I try to use the command prompt I get the following:[image: Maven output snippet]

Nothing happens after this.

Before I changes my standalone.xml  from `<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/> to <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9999}"/>`

I need someone to point me in the direction because it seems like the service listening on port 9999 is not responding to Maven's commands.

Comment: Shouldn't you use wildfly-as plugin instead?

Comment: You are right I should be using the wildfly plugin. I guess I have to go back and see how to migrate the quick starts to wildfly